# Python Server can't restart if C# Client not closed

Tags: c#, python, connection, tcpclient, serversocket

I created a Server with Socket in Python and a client in C# with TCPClient.

My Problem is: When the Client is Connected and I close the Server, the Server cannot restart because

```
    serversocket.bind((host, port))
OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

At my c# Client I have a Threat, that checks if the client has still conection. 
When I close the server I get a message, that the client lost connection and I run:

```
public void Close()
    {
        client.Close();
        client.Client.Dispose();
        client = null;
    }
```

this is my constructor:

```
public HardwareCommunicator(string ip, int port)
    {
        client = new TcpClient(ip, port);
    }
```

I already testet with breakpoint. The Client reaches void Close(), but i cannot restart the server before I close the Clients Gui.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. I added to my Python3 Server

```
serversocket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
```

But I have the feeling that this is just a quick and dirty method!